# Javascript set cookie based on form submitted

Tags: javascript, forms

This is beginners question but I'm stuck.
I have multiple forms on page and I want to set cookie based on which form is submitted.
Ps. I found this code on stack but trying to modify for my needs.

```html
    <html>
    <head>
        <script>
    var today = new Date();
      var expiry = new Date(today.getTime(Nickname) + 30 * 24 * 3600 * 1000);
    
      function setCookie(name, value)
      {
        document.cookie=name + "=" + escape(value) + "; path=/; expires=" + expiry.toGMTString();
      }
    function putCookie(form)
                    //this should set the UserName cookie to the proper value;
      {  
       setCookie("userName", form[0].usrname.value);
    
        return true;
      }
    
      </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <form id="forma1">
     <input type="text" value="Enter Your Nickname" id="nameBox" name='usrname'>
     <input type="button" value="Go!" id="submit" onclick="putCookie(document.getElementsByTagName('form'));"> 
    
    </form>
    <form id="forma2">
     <input type="text" value="Enter Your Nickname" id="nameBox" name='usrname'>
     <input type="button" value="Go!" id="submit" onclick="putCookie(document.getElementsByTagName('form'));">
    </form>
    <form id="forma3">
     <input type="text" value="Enter Your Nickname" id="nameBox" name='usrname'>
     <input type="button" value="Go!" id="submit" onclick="putCookie(document.getElementsByTagName('form'));">
    </form>
    </body>
    
    
    </html>
```

This code working only for forma1, logically because I'm calling form with index [0] but how to accomplish set cookie if forma2 or 3 is submitted?

Comment: Don't pass _all_ the form elements into your function, but only the current one. Since every input element and button has a `form` property pointing to the form it belongs to, you can simply do that via `onclick="putCookie(this.form);` And since you are only passing a single node into your function now, the access via index needs to be removed.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you @CBroe
this is working example.

```html
<html>
<head>
    <script>
  function setCookie(cname, cvalue, exdays) {
  const d = new Date();
  d.setTime(d.getTime() + (exdays*24*60*60*1000));
  let expires = "expires="+ d.toUTCString();
  document.cookie = cname + "=" + cvalue + ";" + expires + ";path=/";
}
function putCookie(form)
    //this should set the UserName cookie to the proper value;
  { 
    var cvalue = form.usrname.value;
    //alert(form.usrname.value);
    //alert(cvalue);    
    setCookie("userName", cvalue, 1);
   
    return true;
  }

  </script>
</head>
<body>
<form id="forma1">
 <input type="text" value="Enter Your Nickname" id="nameBox" name='usrname'>
 <!-- <input type="button" value="Go!" id="submit" onclick="putCookie(document.getElementsByTagName('form'));"> -->
 <input type="button" value="Go!" id="submit" onclick="putCookie(this.form);">
</form>
<form id="forma2">
 <input type="text" value="Enter Your Nickname" id="nameBox" name='usrname'>
 <input type="button" value="Go!" id="submit" onclick="putCookie(this.form);">
</form>
<form id="forma3">
 <input type="text" value="Enter Your Nickname" id="nameBox" name='usrname'>
 <input type="button" value="Go!" id="submit" onclick="putCookie(this.form);">
</form>
<form id="forma4">
 <input type="text" value="Enter Your Nickname" id="nameBox" name='usrname'>
 <input type="button" value="Go!" id="submit" onclick="putCookie(this.form);">
</form>
</body>


</html>
```